# AdMob is not defined on Meteor app

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, admob

I have a Meteor(v1.0.3.1) app and installed AdMob Cordova plugin like this:

```
meteor add cordova:com.google.cordova.admob@https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/tarball/94a31660d1bb35337e3430e2608b7710ea4d882a
```

with the following code as the doc suggests:

```
if(Meteor.isCordova){

    admobid = {
      banner: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    };

    if(AdMob){
        AdMob.createBanner( {
          adId: admobid.banner, 
          position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER, 
          autoShow: true 
        });
      }
}
```

And started the app with `meteor run android-device` with my Android phone plugged in.

The following error appears in the stack trace:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: AdMob is not defined
```

I looked for AdMob object on window and other places but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that the plugin you are using is working. But you should probably not use the tarball. Use the current version (2.7.4) instead.

Try this. This worked for me using the iOS simulator.

1. Remove the plugin you installed with `meteor remove`
2. Install with version number

   `meteor add cordova:com.google.cordova.admob@2.7.4`
3. Run the simluator (use the Android one, if you do not have Xcode )

   `meteor run ios`

Then the AdMob variable should be available. At least it was when I tried it.

**Update**

The plugin also works with Android.

```
`meteor run android`
```

Also, make sure that your code is in `Meteor.startup()`, to ensure that the Cordova plugin is available.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  if (Meteor.isCordova) {
    if (AdMob) {
      AdMob.createBanner( {
        adId: 'ca-app-pub-3080070244198226/2109901818',
        position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
        isTesting: true,
        autoShow: true,
        success: function() {
          console.log("Received ad");
        },
        error: function() {
          console.log("No ad received");
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log("No Admob");
    }
  } else {
    console.log("No Cordova ");
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: the same. I'm running with Android for now.

Comment: I think you need to give us further information. It seems that the issue is not related to the Cordova plugin, but with your setup. What OS are you using, what does the system console say, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to try with this other plugin:

```
meteor add cordova:com.admob.google@https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/tarball/f3851132148aae4c600563d4124cc875c8c5f73e
```

Then in your code:

```
if(Meteor.isCordova){
    if(admob){
        admob.createBannerView({publisherId: "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"});
      }
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting 'Uncaught ReferenceError: admob is not defined' . what could it be

Comment: Are you running it in a browser? I think that plugins are only working in compiled apps (apk's) not in browsers or in app-launchers like phonegap or intel xdk ones...

Answer (score 0):

Meteor had a security upgrade v1.0.4.   You need to add the regex for the website to your mobile config file to get the google sdk.  Otherwise if you dont you will see the whitelist error in x-code's logs.

I used this to get the sdk. 
App.accessRule('*://*googleads.g.doubleclick.net*');

reference from meteor telling you about the upgrade. 
https://www.meteor.com/blog/2015/03/17/meteor-104-mongo-cordova-template-subscriptions