# How to show an AdMob interstitial ad only after a complete level with ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, admob, interstitial

I have implemented the cordova-admob-pro plugin with my Ionic App.

I would like the interstitial ads to show after completing a certain level and **not** when the app loads.

Here is my code:

app.js

```js
// AdMob

    if (window.plugins && window.plugins.AdMob && showAds) {
        DebugService.add('admob OK');
        if (window.plugins && window.plugins.AdMob) {
            var admob_banner_key = device.platform == "Android" ? "ca-app-pub-7...6" : "ca-app-pub-7...0";
            var admob_interstitial_key = device.platform == "Android" ? "ca-app-pub-7...5 " : "ca-app-pub-7...6";
            var admob = window.plugins.AdMob;
            admob.createBannerView(
                    {
                        'publisherId': admob_banner_key,
                        'adSize': admob.AD_SIZE.BANNER,
                        'bannerAtTop': false
                    },
                    function () {
                        admob.requestAd(
                            {'isTesting': true},
                            function () {
                                admob.showAd(true);
                            },
                            function () {
                                DebugService.add('failed to request ad');
                            }
                        );
                    },
                    function () {
                        DebugService.add('failed to create banner view');
                    }
            );
            admob.createInterstitialView(
                    {
                        'publisherId': admob_interstitial_key,
                        'autoShow': false
                    },
                    function() {
                        DebugService.add('interstitial successfully craeted');
                    },
                    function() {
                        DebugService.add('failed to add interstitial :-(');
                    }
            );
        }
    }
```

controller.js:

```js
            if ($scope.levelId % 3 === 0) {
                // after every second level and every third level after that
                DebugService.add("Show interstitial ad :-)");
                if ($localStorage.noAdsPurchased !== true &&
                        window.plugins && window.plugins.AdMob) {
                    DebugService.add('Ready to show interstitial');
                    window.plugins.AdMob.requestInterstitialAd(
                        {'isTesting': true},
                        function() {
                            window.plugins.AdMob.showInterstitialAd(true, 
                                function(){
                                    DebugService.add('interstitial successfully shown');
                                }, 
                                function(){
                                    DebugService.add('interstitial show failed');
                                });
                            DebugService.add('interstitial successfully requested');
                        },
                        function() {
                            DebugService.add('failed to request interstitial');
                        }
                    );
                    DebugService.add('After showing interstitial');
                }
            }
```

The interstitial ad also shows at start, which I don't want. If I remove the code or try and put the code from app.js for interstitial ads only in the controller the interstitial ads do not show at all. I am thinking because they have not be initiated.

How do I initiate interstitial ads without them showing right at the start?

Comment: This one responds also yours: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35362973/513570

Comment: I have added 'autoShow': false, and showInterstitialAd() and the ad no longer shows at startup, but it is also no longer shown after level 2

Comment: Are you sure that showInterstitialAd() is being called? Also, are you sure that you have ads to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input. This is finally how I solved the problem.

It seems that as soon as the `createInterstitialView` method is called the interstitial ad will be shown. That's why it was showing right from the start.

To solve the problem I moved all the AdMob code into its own Service, with methods to initialize, create and show the ads. This way the `createInterstitialView` will not be called until the ad is to be shown. The `createIntersititalView` is called from the controller.

```js
wwdWordRecognition.service('AdmobService', ['DebugService', function (DebugService) {

    var _bannerId;
    var _interstitialId;

    var _isAdmobMissing = function() {
        if(window.plugins === undefined || window.plugins.AdMob === undefined) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    this.init = function(bannerId, interstitialId) {
        _bannerId = bannerId;
        _interstitialId = interstitialId;
    };

    this.createAdmobBanner = function () {
        if(_isAdmobMissing()) {
            return false;
        }
        var _admob = window.plugins.AdMob;
        _admob.createBannerView(
                {
                    'publisherId': _bannerId,
                    'adSize': _admob.AD_SIZE.BANNER,
                    'bannerAtTop': false
                },
                function () {
                    _admob.requestAd(
                        {'isTesting': true},
                        function () {
                            _admob.showAd(true);
                        },
                        function () { DebugService.add('failed to request ad'); }
                    );
                },
                function () { DebugService.add('failed to create banner view');}
        );
    };

    this.showInterstitial = function () {
        if(_isAdmobMissing()) {
            return false;
        }
        DebugService.add('Admob plugin found.');
        var _admob = window.plugins.AdMob;
        _admob.createInterstitialView(
            {
                'publisherId': _interstitialId
            },
            function () {
                DebugService.add('interstitial successfully craeted');
                _admob.requestInterstitialAd(
                    {'isTesting': true},
                    function() {
                        _admob.showInterstitialAd(true, 
                            function(){ DebugService.add('interstitial successfully shown'); }, 
                            function(){ DebugService.add('interstitial show failed'); });
                        DebugService.add('interstitial successfully requested');
                    },
                    function() { DebugService.add('failed to request interstitial'); }
                );
            },
            function () { DebugService.add('failed to add interstitial :-('); }
        );
    };
}]);
```

The app.js now looks like this:

```js
// AdMob

DebugService.add('Start ad setup...');
if (showAds) {
    if (window.plugins && window.plugins.AdMob) {
        var _admob_banner_key = device.platform == "Android" ? "ca-app-pub-7...6" : "ca-app-pub-7...0";
        var _admob_interstitial_key = device.platform == "Android" ? "ca-app-pub-7...5 " : "ca-app-pub-7...6";
        AdmobService.init(_admob_banner_key,_admob_interstitial_key);
        AdmobService.createAdmobBanner();
    } else {
        DebugService.add('Admob plugin not found');
    }
}
```

And finally the controller.js:

```js
if ($scope.listId % 3 === 0) {
    // after every third list
    DebugService.add("Show interstitial ad.");
    if ($localStorage.noAdsPurchased !== true &&
             window.plugins && window.plugins.AdMob) {
        AdmobService.showInterstitial();
    }
}
```